# Python initial read from socket returns some unexpected characters

Tags: python, sockets

I have a Python socket server that I'm trying to read text commands from a line at a time, code is below.  The first time it is run, line contains what look like some garbage characters before the data.  On subsequent calls to readline I get the exact data I typed in from the telnet client (Putty).  Why am I getting these first few apparent garbage characters.  E.g. if I type in `_return_`, line contains `\u18\u01\u03d\r\n`
'

```
    HOST = ''
    PORT = 27001
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    while True:
        conn, address = s.accept()
        print 'Got new CLI connection'
        f = conn.makefile()
        f.flush()
        while True:
            try:
                self.PrintBanner(conn)
                self.PrintMenu(conn)
                line = f.readline()
                if line.lower()[:1] == 'd':
                    self.MenuFieldRequestStatus(conn)
                    f.readline()
            except:
                s.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure and use "RAW" mode in this case. Otherwise, your telnet client is trying to discover and negotiate with a telnet server. See this link for more info:

[3.6 Making raw TCP connections](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.61/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-rawprot)

You could probably switch "Telnet negotiation mode" to passive in the Telnet settings area too.